# I'm trying to figure out a way to sort data from column A into separate columns based on the data in column B

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Okay so I'm probably missing something obvious here but I'm trying to figure out how to sort things from my data entry box into separate columns based on what they input.

My data entry box ("QUICK ADD") asks for a URL and a city (from a list of cities). Then it returns on the Database sheet the URL in column A and the city in Column B.

My goal is to sort the URLs into separate columns for each city so A1 would go into B1's corresponding column.

Hope that makes sense!

[image: My data entry form]

[image: My data base sheet]

Answer (score 0):

#### A into Bs column

```
function aintobscolumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const hsc = 4;//header start column
  const hA = sh.getRange(1, 4, 1, sh.getLastColumn() - hsc + 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => {idx[h] = i + hsc - 1});
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    r[idx[r[1]]] = r[0];
  })
  sh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example.com?1 | COL4 |  | example.com?1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?2 | COL5 |  |  | example.com?2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?3 | COL6 |  |  |  | example.com?3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?4 | COL7 |  |  |  |  | example.com?4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?5 | COL8 |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?6 | COL9 |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?7 | COL10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?8 | COL11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?9 | COL12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?10 | COL13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?11 | COL14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?12 | COL15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?12 |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?13 | COL16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?13 |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?14 | COL17 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?14 |  |  |  |
| example.com?15 | COL18 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?15 |  |  |
| example.com?16 | COL19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?16 |  |
| example.com?17 | COL20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | example.com?17 |
| example.com?18 | COL4 |  | example.com?18 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?19 | COL5 |  |  | example.com?19 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| example.com?20 | COL6 |  |  |  | example.com?20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |